# How to select all the input of child of ul list when parent input [checkbox] is chekced?

Tags: jquery

I want to check all the child input of list when parent input [checkbox] is checked.

```
<dd id="space_content">
<ul>
    <li parent-id="0" li-id="16"><input type="checkbox" value="16"/>Anthropology Department 
    <ul>
        <li parent-id="16" li-id="18"><input type="checkbox" value="18"/>Anthropology Faculty Collections
        </li>
        <li parent-id="16" li-id="23"><input type="checkbox" value="23"/>Shared Collections</li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li parent-id="0" li-id="45"><input type="checkbox" value="45"/>Center for asdf on Vermont</li>
<li parent-id="0" li-id="19"><input type="checkbox" value="19"/>Center for Research on Vermont
    <ul>
        <li parent-id="19" li-id="24"><input type="checkbox" value="24"/>Collections for Testing
            <ul>
               <li parent-id="24" li-id="25"><input type="checkbox" value="25"/>Geology Department
                </li> 
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</dd>
```

So far this is what I did but could not go any further.

```
$(function(){    
    $("#space_content > ul > li > input").click(function(){

       if($(this).is(':checked')){
           var $parent = $("#space_content > ul > li").children("ul");
           if($parent.has('input')){
               $parent.children('input').attr('checked','checked');
           }

        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: can you post a fiddle please

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kJd5a/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `next()` to get the next `ul` and find `checkboxes` in it and assign the current checkbox status to them. As you have checkboxes it better to go for them instead of `input` for being specific. Also use change event instead of click.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/87L3u/3/)**

```
$(function(){    
    $("#space_content > ul > li :checkbox").change(function(){    
      $(this).next('ul').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: this is not working when clicking on node `Collections for Testing`

Comment: Thanks @Usman, This was due to selector for binding the event, check it now.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(function () {
    $("#space_content > ul input").click(function () {
        $(this).next('ul').find('input').prop('checked', this.checked)
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kJd5a/)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.change()` event instead of `.click()` for input elements as well as using `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` to set the checked state of your checkbox. You can shorten your code to:

```
$(function(){    
    $("#space_content > ul > li > input").change(function(){    
        $(this).next().find('input').prop('checked', this.checked);
    }); 
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/juFxf/)**

---

If you got problem with `.change()` event in old browser such as IE8, you can use `.click()` instead:

```
$(function(){    
    $("#space_content > ul > li > input").click(function(){    
        $(this).next().find('input').prop('checked', this.checked);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: couldn't disagree more. .change() doesn't fire until focus is lost on the checkbox  in IE8. .click() is the most appropriate for a checkbox.

Comment: jsfiddle doesn't even work for me in ie8 mode. But I know for a fact .change() doesn't fire until you click somewhere else after clicking the checkbox in IE8. I had an issue with this last week. If it works for you that's an exception not a rule and your information is going to lead someone to a problem. If you have a good reason to use change instead of click on a checkbox i'd love to hear it.

Comment: @Bryan Ok, I've added your suggestion.

Comment: Don't mean to be a prick about it, just I had an issue that took me a while to figure out. Don't want others to experience the same issue. thanks for including it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you wanted..I have sample code for your need

```
   $(".pc-box").click(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            $(this).closest("li").find(".cc-box").prop("checked", true);
            $(this).parent().fadeOut();
        }  
    });
```

Demo :-

http://jsfiddle.net/mrc4N/9/

Answer (score 0):

if u go thru a `Jquery` you can do this simple 
For this you need to add `jquery lib`

```
$(function () {
    $("#space_content > ul input").click(function () {

        $(this).next('ul').find('input').prop('checked', this.checked);

    });
});
```

Here is [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/sokuwoge/1/) exmple

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/25AHf/8/)

```
$(function(){    
    $("#space_content > ul > li > input").click(function(){

       if($(this).is(':checked')){
           $(this).next('ul').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);


        }
        else
        {
             $(this).next('ul').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', '');
        }
    }); 
});
```

this will check all the child `checkboxes` and **uncheck as well**

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(function(){    
    $("#space_content > ul > li > input").click(function(){
      $(this).siblings().find(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
    }); 
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FAY83/)